# What are the steps to create a Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, login

What are the steps to create an account on Stack Overflow?

It's not redirecting to the page for creating an account. It cannot display the webpage, at least not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: You can access at the least with an openid. Create one and try it. [OpenID Info](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use any OpenID provider to create an account - for example, including (but not limited to) the 13 with [buttons on the login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login). If you don't happen to use any of those services, and don't want to create anything new, the Stack Exchange OpenID provider is trivial to [setup here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login#create-account). If that page doesn't load, check you aren't blocking `https://openid.stackexchange.com` or iframes.